# NSURL and russian domains

Tags: swift, nsurl, cyrillic

That's a problem and i cannot find the solution. In my program i try to open Safari with url, and that was ok until the occasion: i tried to link the site with russian host and domain, for example:

```
let url = "http://карта.рф"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
```

Then i have an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So the class NSURL cannot make an object on a link having russian symbols. I tried to use **url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!** and similar, but the problem is that it change ALL "incorrect" symbols onto others, but it's necessary to link exactly russian sites, in russian domains, which means there are no really incorrect letters in url-address.

I don't believe that the NSURL cannot work with non-english symbols. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @HamzaAnsari , it's just similar, but doesn't clarify all i want.

Comment: @kennytm , that's absolutely not what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the character set related to the **host**

```
let string = "http://" + "карта.рф".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
let url = NSURL(string:string)
```

If you have to encode also `path` and `query` use `NSURLComponents` and encode the other components separately.

```
let components = NSURLComponents()
components.scheme = "http"
components.host = "карта.рф".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

let url = components.URL!
```

Comment: I think Apple wants us to use `URLComponents` now. Those double slashes breaks the url since they get encoded as well.

Comment: @vadian, this solves the problem, although the usual print(url) shows the abracadabra, of course, But in Safari that's the correct address.

Comment: I updated the answer to preserve `http://` in the first example.

Comment: On the whole, the situation is that the user inputs the usual string as a url-address, and after that the Safari tries to open it. So there's no division into path, query, host or smth else.

Comment: @vadian, as i see, there's no any variant except the encoding by components? is there a way to convert the whole string, like we do it copy-pasting into the search field in browser?

Comment: I have no idea, you might split the string programmatically by `pathComponents` encode the parts and join them back together.

Comment: @vadian, ok, thank you!